# Profile popups in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to web design and am working on a project just now for a charity and am looking to add profile popup DIV's or windows preferably the 1st...
Not sure whats the best way to go about it!!

Can anyone advise please.

Thank you

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that...

Comment: On the site I have members and want to show a small photo and a paragraph on the person. So when you click the name a small window or DIV will open and show their profile.... Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but for beginners in web design, you might want to use an iframe. It is a HTML tag that creates inline panel/window thing and is pretty easy to use. It looks something like this:

```
<iframe src="profile.html" width="300" height="300">
<p>Text here will be displayed on a browser that doesn't support iframe</p>
</iframe>
```

I have not played around with them that much but you can probably pull off the showing the profile with a little bit of JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".avatar").mouseenter(function(){ //The .avatar would be the element of the place where the person clicks on the profile or whatever.
        $("iframe").fadeTo("fast",1);
    });
    $("iframe").mouseleave(function(){ 
        $("iframe").fadeTo("fast",0);
    });
});
```

Something like this should work. I'm not really sure what you were looking for but I hope this helped.

**Useful Link**

- [iframe Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)